# Silverlight Custom Button content

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

What would be a good way to have the text (content) of buttons per-client configurable in a SL 4 app?  I'm still pretty novice w/ SL so this may seem trivial.

The issue isn't new.  The system currently has a static XAML attribute for ButtonA's content as "Do Stuff" (Content="DoStuff").  Now one client wants that to read "Do Things".  This will continue to crop up on occasion in arbitrary places across the system.

I have a dictionary available that will contain the custom text, but would LIKE (if possible) to be able to have a default value and only override **if** there is a dictionary entry.

Conceptually, it would be nice to be able to have:

```
<Button Content="Do Stuff" OverrideContentKey="ButtonAOverrideContent" />
```

where if the dictionary has a key of ButtonAOverrideContent, it will override it, but otherwise "Do Stuff" will show.

Is there a way to perhaps write a converter and make some entries in App.xaml that would then allow all buttons to conditionally override the content?  What I've seen of converters looks like there's not a smooth way to pass information about the control (e.g. the override key) to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a  `ConverterParameter` property of a `Binding` to pass your override content key to a converter.

```
public class ReplaceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string key = (string)parameter;
        var someDictionary = GetYourReplacementDictionary();
        if (someDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return someDictionary[key];
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your App.Xaml resources:-

```
 <local:ReplaceConverter x:Key="replacer" />
```

Then on a button:-

```
 <Button Content="{Binding Source='Do Stuff', ConverterParameter=ButtonAOverrideContent, Converter={StaticResource replacer}}" />
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously useful :)  Will give it a try.  Thanks!